# Rails 5: Show a single selected child object in parent view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a website for a band. In this website, there are multiple albums. Each album `has_many` songs. Each song `belongs_to` only one album. Songs can be uploaded by the band through a user login. I have run into several problems and I'm not sure what the source might be.

I cannot access the edit method for songs in the views. In development, there is currently one song uploaded and playable (all is working perfectly here), however when I try to add an edit link I get a missing id for nil error. I'm not sure where that is coming from:

SongsController:

```
def edit
  @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
  @song = @album.songs.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
  @song = @album.songs.find(params[:id])
  if @song.update_attributes(song_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Song updated"
    redirect_to album_url(@album)
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Album Show:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Song', edit_album_song_path(@album, @song) %>
```

Error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :album_id=>"1", :controller=>"songs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

An even bigger problem is that I can't access the attributes for a song in the view. I want there to be a list of associated songs inside each album (this works well). When you click on a song it plays the uploaded mp3 in a fixed HTML5 audio player embedded on the page. This should also change the view to show the details of the currently selected song (lyrics, title, etc). But I get `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`.

AlbumsController:

```
def show
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  @songs = @album.songs
end
```

SongsController:

```
def show
  @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
  @song = @album.song.find(params[:id])
end
```

(I have also tried without the album reference here with the same error resulting)

Album show.html.erb view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1 class="page-title"><%= @album.title %></h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 tracklist">

      <%= render 'layouts/tracklist' %>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 current-song">

      <%= render 'songs/show' %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Songs _show.html.erb

```
<%= @song.title %>

<br />

<%= @song.lyrics %>

<%= link_to 'Edit Song', edit_album_song_path(@album, @song) %>
```

Error for edit path (removing all other code):

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :album_id=>"album-title", :controller=>"songs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Error for model attributes (removing all other code):

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

The nil class properly finds the album, but is apparently missing the song. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the code here. Everything seems to be set up properly, but it's still missing it.

How do I properly implement this functionality? Apologies if this is a very simple fix that I'm missing, but I've scoured the code as well as many different combinations of solutions from google and stackoverflow searches, all of which have failed to fix the issue.

Edit: Routes:

```
resources albums do
  resources songs
end
```

Comment: Can you post song & album routes?

Comment: Routes are nested 'resources albums do resources songs end'

Comment: None of these answers fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :album_id=>"album-title",
>   :controller=>"songs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

The error is because `@song` is `nil` in the link.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Song', edit_album_song_path(@album, @song) %>
```

You didn't defined `@song` in `albums#show`. You have `@songs` not `@song`. You have to iterate over `@songs` in the view like below

```
#_show.html.erb
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
  <%= song.title %>
  <br />
  <%= song.lyrics %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit Song', edit_album_song_path(@album, song) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use nested routes?

If no try implement this

*config/routes.rb*

`resources :albums do
  resources :songs
end`

Answer (score 0):

Error message is `missing required keys: [:id]`, so I think maybe bellow code will works.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Song', edit_album_song_path(album_id: @album.id, id: @song.id) %>
```

If you can post `bundle exec rake routes` output, maybe we can find better ways to fix this problem.

Hope it helps.